# django.db.utils.OperationalError when running MySQL/MariaDB in Docker: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'

Tags: mysql, django, docker, mariadb

Running MySQL/MariaDB in a Docker container:

```bash
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name $(DATABASE_NAME) -v /tmp/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_DATABASE=$(DATABASE_NAME) -e MYSQL_USER=$(DATABASE_USER) -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$(DATABASE_PASSWORD) -d mariadb:latest > /dev/null
```

And then running Django version 4 locally with:

```bash
manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
```

#### Error

```bash
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 2")
```

I can successfully connect to the database with MySQL Workbench as well as the command:

```bash
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p <database>
```

I am launching Django and the MySQL/MariaDB Docker container from a Makefile.

#### Makefile

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

.PHONY: dj-start-local
dj-start-local: start-mysql
    PYTHONPATH=. django_project/src/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000

.PHONY: start-mysql
start-mysql:
    docker run -p 3306:3306 --name $(DATABASE_NAME) \
        -v /tmp/mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
        -e MYSQL_DATABASE=$(DATABASE_NAME) \
        -e MYSQL_USER=$(DATABASE_USER) \
        -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$(DATABASE_PASSWORD) \
        -d mariadb:latest > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `healthcheck.sh` in the container. Use the `MARIADB_MYSQL_LOCALHOST_USER=1` to create a `mysql@localhost` user that the script can use to access the database,

The healthcheck waits until its fully started regardless of the time.

Makefile:

```
.PHONY: start-mariadb
start-mariadb:
    docker run -p 3306:3306 --name $(DATABASE_NAME) \
        -e MARIADB_DATABASE=$(DATABASE_NAME) \
        -e MARIADB_USER=$(DATABASE_USER) \
        -e MARIADB_PASSWORD=$(DATABASE_PASSWORD) \
        -e MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$(DATABASE_PASSWORD) \
        -e MARIADB_MYSQL_LOCALHOST_USER=1 \
        -v /tmp/mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
        -d mariadb:latest
    while ! docker exec $(DATABASE_NAME) healthcheck.sh --su=mysql --connect --innodb_initialized; do sleep 1; done
    docker exec --user mysql $(DATABASE_NAME) mariadb -e 'select "hello world"'
```

Test run:

```
$ make start-mariadb 
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name dd \
    -e MARIADB_DATABASE=dd \
    -e MARIADB_USER=dd \
    -e MARIADB_PASSWORD=dd \
    -e MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=dd \
    -e MARIADB_MYSQL_LOCALHOST_USER=1 \
    -d mariadb:latest
53066fffa293ed061743024e387bd7fb6f1c664efd603c7a657ba88e307be308
while ! docker exec dd healthcheck.sh --su=mysql --connect --innodb_initialized; do sleep 1; done
healthcheck connect failed
healthcheck connect failed
healthcheck connect failed
healthcheck connect failed
docker exec --user mysql dd mariadb -e 'select "hello world"'
hello world
hello world
```

Note: added `MARIADB_PASSWORD` otherwise the database/user wouldn't be created.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be due to a race condition, where Django is attempting to connect to the database before it is ready. Try waiting a few seconds after starting the Docker container.

### Simple Solution

#### Makefile

```
.PHONY: start-mysql
start-mysql:
    docker run -p 3306:3306 --name $(DATABASE_NAME) \
        -v /tmp/mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
        -e MYSQL_DATABASE=$(DATABASE_NAME) \
        -e MYSQL_USER=$(DATABASE_USER) \
        -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$(DATABASE_PASSWORD) \
        -d mariadb:latest
    sleep 4
```

### Better Solution using healthcheck.sh

In [**Dan Black's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73044360/1164465), he pointed out that the MariaDB docker container includes a script [**healthcheck.sh**](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/master/healthcheck.sh).

If you only want to check if the MariaDB container can receive connections, then `healthcheck.sh` can be run without specifying a user (avoiding authorization complications).

The Makefile below will check for a database connection every second until the database is ready.

#### Makefile (advanced version)

```
.PHONY: mysql-start
mysql-start: mysql-stop
    docker run -p 3306:3306 --name $(DATABASE_NAME) \
        -v /tmp/mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
        -e MYSQL_DATABASE=$(DATABASE_NAME) \
        -e MYSQL_USER=$(DATABASE_USER) \
        -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$(DATABASE_PASSWORD) \
        -d mariadb:latest
    while ! docker exec $(DATABASE_NAME) healthcheck.sh --connect 2> /dev/null; do sleep 1; done
```